# round off a screw head = strip a screw head?

Tags: word-meaning

From [Aviation SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/11155/removing-screws-from-cessna-wing-tank-cover):

> We need to replace the fuel tanks on a Cessna 150 and the screws holding the wing cover won't come out. They are just frozen in place. I think that the paint also may be working against us: Getting the paint out of the screw heads has been difficult. So far no screw heads have been **rounded off**.

Is a **rounded off** screw head the same as a **stripped** head, that is, a head with its notches disrupted due to excessive force applied by the instrument?

Comment: I agree with Gary's explanation on rounding off. I'd be more inclined in this type of scenario to describe the screw-thread as stripped, rather than the head - 'stripped thread' is a common usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Although "rounded off" usually applies to outside corners -- for example, the corners on a bolt head that allow a wrench to grip -- it can apply to inside corners as well.  Given this use of the term, it seems likely that these are Phillips head screws.  A crosspoint driver needs those inside corners to grip.

Paint was removed from (at least some of) the screw head slots.  The screw heads were undamaged.  Even so, the screws wouldn't turn.